# Html show/hide password not working JavaScript included

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I have a form and I have a pic of password visibility and I want that when I click on that image I want yo show password I have wrote onclick="my function()" on the IMG and Id password on the password input but its not working
Code: https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/19ba2d6e12e24d74b49a1421c8b98cea
The code was big so I paste it in paste.gg and I gave link here this link will take you to the code

Comment: please include your code here so we can help you instead of the link.

Comment: The link take you to the code

Comment: I pasted your code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chm1pszd/) and works as expected, don't understand where your problem is..

Comment: the code is working fine for me too can you please explain where is the problem ?

Comment: The problem is that when I write a password and even I click on the visibility pic the password don't show as text I think I need z index I I'll try

Comment: No even when I use the z index I don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you posted on paste.gg you are trying to reference the javascript with `<script src"signup.js"></script>`. If that is the case, you are missing a `=`. Also I recommend to use `defer` to have the DOM available in the script.

It should be `<script src="signup.js" defer></script>`.

In the future, you might want to check the Console in the Developer Tools (usually F12). There might be some useful error logs that could help you determine why something is not working.

Comment: Thanks I will fix it and tell if the error is gone